# Newline not preserved when reading from Textarea

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

My java webapp fetches content from a textarea, and e-mails the same.

The problem I'm facing is that the newline character in the textarea message is not preserved when reading the same using

```
request.getParameter("message");
```

Any clues how it can be tackled?

TIA.

`EDIT:`

The content in the textarea is:
abcd
abcd

CODE:

```
String message = request.getParameter("message");

        System.out.println("index loc for message "+message+" using \\r\\n : "+message.indexOf("\r\n"));
        System.out.println("index loc for message "+message+" using \\n : "+message.indexOf("\n"));
        System.out.println("index loc for message "+message+" using \\r : "+message.indexOf("\r"));
        System.out.println("index loc for message "+message+" using \\n\\r : "+message.indexOf("\n\r"));
```

OUTPUT:

> index loc for message asdfasdf using \r\n : -1
>   index loc for message asdfasdf using \n : -1
>   index loc for message asdfasdf using \r : -1
>   index loc for message asdfasdf using \n\r : -1

Comment: you just need to do encodeURIComponent($("#idOfTextArea")) in the request url in javascript and only get value by request.getParameter("textareaname")  and save into DB

Answer (score 3):

That completely depends on how you're **redisplaying** it.

It sounds like that you're redisplaying it in HTML. "Raw" newlines are not part of HTML markup. Do a rightclick, *View Page Source* in webbrowser. You'll see linebreaks over all place. Usually before and/or after HTML tags.

In order to visually present linebreaks in the HTML presentation, you should actually be using `<br>` tags. You can replace newlines by `<br>` strings as below:

```
message = message.replace("\n", "<br>");
```

This is only sensitive to [XSS attack holes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application) if the `message` is an user-controlled variable, because you have to present it unescaped in JSP (i.e. without `<c:out>`) in order to get `<br>` to work. You thus need to make sure that the `message` variable is [sanitized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410526/how-to-implement-a-possibility-for-user-to-post-some-html-formatted-data-in-a-sa) beforehand.

Alternatively, you can also set CSS `white-space` property there where you're redisplaying the message to `pre`. If you'd like to wrap lines inside the context of a block element, then set `pre-wrap`. Or if you'd like to collapse spaces and tabs as well, then set `pre-line`.

```html
<div id="message"><c:out value="${message}" /></div>
```

```css
#message {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

This will display the text preformatted (as a textarea by default does).

Comment: We know he's shipping the text out by e-mail, but we don't know how the text is being displayed once it arrives. If it's indeed being displayed as HTML, there's a lot of work to be done indeed. Just maintaining line breaks would be just a small part of the problem, as the users could maliciously or accidentally introduce all kinds of harmful tags into the text.

Comment: Nice answer. you mean `replaceAll`?

Comment: @mdma: No, certainly not. Regex is overkill for a simple char(s)-by-char(s) replace.

Comment: @BalusC. I'd not noticed that replace() also takes a CharSequence, and it's only been in there since 1.5 so I've only had 4 or so years to notice... ;-)

Comment: @mdma: It's indeed unfortunately one of the least known methods in `String`. I've even ever downvotes for that here at SO because a sad nitpicker thought that it wouldn't compile!

Comment: @balusc which is not really surprising, as google often points you to 1.4 javadocs when you google a java class, e.g. http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=java.util.hashmap

Comment: @sean: That's exactly why I google in this style: [hashmap /6 site:oracle.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=hashmap+%2F6+site%3Aoracle.com)

Comment: I'm displaying it as plain text.

Comment: @BalusC: Firstly, thanks for the effort you've put in.  
I tried the code, and it's working perfect. But in my actual implementation, it's not. Could it be because I'm sending the parameters using javascript?(I'm using ajax).

Answer (score 1):

Two possible problems:

- The text in the textarea is word wrapped and doesn't really have any newlines.
- The String you get with `getParameter()` contains newlines (`\n`) but no carriage returns (`\r`) as expected by many email programs.

As a first step, I'd try dumping the retrieved String in a way you can check for this. You could write to a file and use `od` or a hex editor to look at the file, for example.

If it turns out you're simply missing CRs, you could do some simple regexp-based replacement on the string to fix that.

Comment: The getParameter() definitely doesn't contain newlines(\n). Because the string concatenated to it, and having newlines(\n), are getting displayed properly, but not the message obtained from textarea.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe CRs? I find it hard to believe a browser would not send *any* line terminator.

Comment: The browser does in fact. When I display the value from javascript using `alert`, it does display the content in respective lines

Comment: OK, I give up. The only way I'd see to fix your problem would be for me to set up a project to duplicate some of what you're doing, and that's more work than I'm willing to do. Hopefully you or someone else manages to come up with a bright insight eventually, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Searching the ASCII codes i found that the new line is not defined like the often `\n`, instead is defined like `\r\n`.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `encodeURIComponent()` before submitting the form and `decodeURIComponent()` on the server side.