# How to implement a possibility for user to post some html-formatted data in a safe way?

Tags: java, security, jsf

I have a `textarea` and I want to support some simplest formatting for posted data (at least, whitespaces and line breaks).

How can I achieve this? If I will not escape the response and keep some html tags then it'll be a great security hole. But I don't see any other solution which will allow text formatting in browser.

So, I probably should filter user's input. But how can I do this? Are there any ready to use solutions? I'm using JSF so are there any smart component which filters everything except html tags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a HTML parser which supports HTML filtering against a whitelist like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org). Here's an extract of relevance from [its site](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer).

> ### [Sanitize untrusted HTML](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer)
>
> #### Problem
>
> You want to allow untrusted users to supply HTML for output on your website (e.g. as comment submission). You need to clean this HTML to avoid [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS) attacks.
>
> #### Solution
>
> Use the jsoup HTML [`Cleaner`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Cleaner.html) with a configuration specified by a [`Whitelist`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html).
>
> ```
> String unsafe = 
>       "<p><a href='http://example.com/' onclick='stealCookies()'>Link</a></p>";
> String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());
>       // now: <p><a href="http://example.com/" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p>
> ```

And then to display it with whitespace preserved, apply CSS `white-space: pre-wrap;` on the HTML element where you're displaying it.

No all-in-one JSF component comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason why you need to accept HTML instead of some other markup language, such as markdown (which is what StackOverflow uses)?

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Not sure what kind of tags you'd want to accept that wouldn't be covered by md or a similar formatting language...

Comment: To reasons spring to mind: Markdown actually allows arbitrary HTML, so you still need to scrub it server-side. And allowing server-side cleaned HTML means you can use a rich text editor, rather than expecting users to learn a markup language.

Comment: +1 Both good points: one of which I didn't know, the other didn't occur me.

Comment: More authorative you can't get ;) (Jonathan is the creator of Jsoup).