# How would I remove all HTML attributes in HTML tags in a string

Tags: java, regex, html-parsing

I am trying to take a string that has HTML, strip out some tags (img, object) and all other HTML tags, strip out their attributes.  For example:

```
<div id="someId" style="color: #000000">
   <p class="someClass">Some Text</p>
   <img src="images/someimage.jpg" alt="" />
   <a href="somelink.html">Some Link Text</a>
</div>
```

Would become:

```
<div>
   <p>Some Text</p>
   Some Link Text
</div>
```

I am trying:

```
string.replaceAll("<\/?[img|object](\s\w+(\=\".*\")?)*\>", ""); //REMOVE img/object
```

I am not sure how to strip all attributes inside a tag though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do this is 1 regex.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do this with regex.

Comment: I don't need it to be one regex, just something that makes sense and will do what I need.  how would you recommend doing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove all attributes like this:

```
string.replaceAll("(<\\w+)[^>]*(>)", "$1$2");
```

This expression matches an opening tag, but captures only its header `<div` and the closing `>` as groups 1 and 2. `replaceAll` uses *references* to these groups to join them back in the output as `$1$2`. This cuts out the attributes in the middle of the tag.

Comment: For some reason this is giving me a java.lang.NullPointerException error.

Comment: @fanfavorite It should not, unless your string is `null`.

Comment: I check if it is null or empty before I do anything. If I change the replaceAll part it works fine, so not sure what is happening with the replaceAll portion.

Comment: @fanfavorite Could you add console output or check the value in the debugger right before the call to `replaceAll`? I checked this expression in the online tester [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html), and it works exactly the way you need it to work.

Comment: Note that this does not remove the `<a>` tag whereby its body is left, as shown in the desired result.

Comment: @BalusC This could be addressed by running the "kill tags" transform from the OP *after* the removal of attributes. Of course `a` would need to be added to the list of tags that need to be removed, along with `img` and `object` that are currently there.

Answer (score 8):

I would not recommend regex for this if you want to filter specific tags. This is going to be hell of a job and never going to be fully reliable. Use a normal HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org). It offers the [`Whitelist`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html) API to clean up HTML. See also [this cookbook document](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer).

Here's a kickoff example with help of Jsoup which only allows `<div>` and `<p>` tags next to the standard set of tags of the chosen `Whitelist` which is [`Whitelist#simpleText()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html#simpleText%28%29) in the below example.

```java
String html = "<div id='someId' style='color: #000000'><p class='someClass'>Some Text</p><img src='images/someimage.jpg' alt='' /><a href='somelink.html'>Some Link Text</a></div>";
Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.simpleText(); // Whitelist.simpleText() allows b, em, i, strong, u. Use Whitelist.none() instead if you want to start clean.
whitelist.addTags("div", "p");
String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, whitelist);
System.out.println(clean);
```

This results in

```html
<div>
   <p>Some Text</p>Some Link Text
</div>
```

#### See also:

- [How to implement a possibility for user to post some html-formatted data in a safe way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410526/how-to-implement-a-possibility-for-user-to-post-some-html-formatted-data-in-a-sa)

Comment: It’s very difficult to tell people that very few users of regexes are up to even simple applications of regexes when it comes to tags.  Everyone thinks they know both, and almost no one does. So it kinda comes down to saying “you’re not smart enough” in some socially acceptable way. Rather tough to phrase constructively.

Answer (score 1):

`/<(/?\w+) .*?>/<\1>/` might work - takes the tag (the matching group) and reads any attributes until the close bracket and replaces it with just the backets and the tag.

Answer (score -1):

Probably would be much easier if you are using a SAX or DOM, and take the node name and value, and remove all attributes.