# textarea preformatting and wrapping in h:outputText

Tags: html, css, jsf-2, textarea, newline

I am saving news from textarea in database and showing them again on a JSF page.

When I print the bean data I have it as below.

> This is line 1
>   This is line 2

In textarea when I try to edit, I see same as above. But when I try to print in `<h:outputText>` I see it as below.

> This is line 1 This is line 2

Even when I print using `Sytem.out.println()`, I see output as

> This is line 1 This is line 2

Any idea how can I get this new line in `<h:outputText>`?

---

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647274/houtputtext-is-not-breaking-lines-in-n) which suggests to use `white-space: pre`.

This is working, but when the length of the text is long, all long line is coming in one line instead of next line and because of that I am getting horizontal scrollbar which is not what I want.

This answer works fine for small text but as news are large in length, this is problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want both preformatting *and* wrapping, use instead:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

If you want to support IE6/7 as well (which doesn't support `pre-wrap`), use instead:

```
white-space: pre;
word-wrap: break-word;
```