# How would I redisplay user-controlled input from a h:inputTextarea preserving linebreaks with JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

After some googling I found that JSF generally sanitizes all user-input during display through any component by default, the best option I see is displaying the user-input through an `h:outputText` with escaping explicitly disabled, like so:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.userInput}" escape="false" />
```

But this requires me to sanitize the input myself, then replacing linebreaks by `<br />` tags manually and hoping it is all stable and safe (what if the doctype switches from XHTML to HTML5 for example? I would have to manually change the `<br />` to a `<br>` in my code etc.). For sanitation I was thinking of using the Apache Commons helper function `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()`:

```
myBean.setUserInput(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(userInput)
    .replaceAll("(\r\n|\r|\n|\n\r)", "<br />"));
```

..but this leaves me with another depedency and writing my own HTML escape function probably just opens Pandora's outputbox..

So is there a "best practice" clean and solid JSF way to accomplish this seemingly simple and common use case?

(I'm also already using RichFaces if that helps)

---

**Edit**: The apparent duplicate isn't one, as it also introduces another dependency and ignores my core question: whether there is a way to preserve the linebreaks without doing my own escaping and without replacing linebreaks by literal `<br />` tags myself in the first place. Just preserving the linebreaks.

**Edit 2**: Question sufficiently answered by the links in the comments.

Comment: As you seem to worry more about linebreaks than about sanitizing, here are other dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410526/how-to-implement-a-possibility-for-user-to-post-some-html-formatted-data-in-a-sa/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210987/textarea-preformatting-and-wrapping-in-houtputtext/

Comment: I've seen the edit. Still looks like a dupe to me. As BalusC says, [CSS white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) is probably what you're looking for, but that's just basic CSS, nothing to do with JSF or any other web framework.

Comment: You can always use `<pre>`. The linebreaks are being preserved, browsers just ignore them.