# How to show output text in separate lines

Tags: html, jsf, line-breaks

I have two `String` properties in my managed bean along with corresponding getters and setters.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class EditorBean implements Serializable {

    private String value="hello how are you";
    private String message="hello how are you";

    public EditorBean() {
        value="hello how are you guys?";
        message="dd";
    }

    // ...
}
```

I would like to render both strings in separate lines.

```
<h:outputText value="#{editorBean.message}" /> 
<h:outputText value="#{editorBean.value}" />
```

But they are shown in a single line.

> ddhello how are you guys?

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: can you put more code pelase, this not helpful at all

Comment: sorry its edited now

Comment: your program work fine check my answer now

Comment: Please start by learning some basic html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [h:outputText does not break \r\n characters into new lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647274/houtputtext-does-not-break-r-n-characters-into-new-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no problem with your program i test your program and i get a result like this :

[image]

So it show you this because you already change the values in your Constructor :

```
public EditorBean() {
    value="hello how are you guys?";
    message="dd";
}
```

so it should you `ddhello how are you guys?`
------------------------^-------^

So if you want to show :

```
private String value="hello how are you";
private String message="hello how are you";
```

You should not initialize them again in your constructor.

**Note**

Try this to see what happen exactly :

```
Message = <h:outputText value="#{editorBean.message}"  /> 
<br/>
Value = <h:outputText value="#{editorBean.value}" />
```