# How can I display line breaks (as entered in inputTextArea) in a jsf datatable?

Tags: html, css, jsf, richfaces

Here is an simplified code sample, for what I'm trying to do. A text entered above in an inputTextArea is correctly displayed (**with** Line Breaks).

Below, in the dataTable, the same text is displayed **without** Line breaks.

```
<h:form id=myInputText#{id}>
    <h:inputTextarea id="myInputText" value="#{form.textWithLinebreaks}"/>
</h:form>

<h:form id=myOutput>
    <rich:dataTable 
        id="myTable"
        value="#{form.model}"
        var="f"
        style="table-layout: fixed;"
        styleClass="wordWrap"
        rows="5">

    <a4j:support event="onRowClick"
        action="#{action.selectText(f)}"
        immediate="true" reRender="myInputText#{id}" />

    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
                TextShouldHaveLineBreaks
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{f.text}"/>
    </rich:column>

</rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Things I tried to fix this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{f.text}" style="white-space: pre-wrap"/>
```

doesn't Change anything.

I also tried using a readonly inputTextArea as a workaound:

```
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
                TextShouldHaveLineBreaks
            </f:facet>
            <h:inputTextarea value="#{f.text}" style="white-space: pre-wrap" readonly="true"/>
    </rich:column>
```

This doesn't help either, and will require lots of css to look just like all other columns.

Just in case this is relevant: My application runs on Seam with Richfaces 3.3.

Comment: Should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647274/houtputtext-does-not-break-r-n-characters-into-new-lines check client-side what the differences are

Comment: Which solution specifically do you mean, @Kukeltje? The css solution `style="white-space: pre-wrap"`worked fine for me in another project (uses Primefaces instead, and the relevant cell was in an `<p:cellEditor...>` element. I can't get this to work in this case.

Comment: Yes, and that is why I stated to check **client-side** in the html. See what css **is** applied... Is yours overridden...?

Comment: The css is applied correctly - it is not overriden. And I get the same result with several browsers.

Comment: But is **other** css applied as well? Try disabling those and see if it makes a difference...

Comment: I decided to use the `<inputTextarea readonly="true" />` Workaround in the end. It solves my problem and may even turn out to be useful. However, it still bothers me that I was not able to accomplish my original idea...

Comment: _"However, it still bothers me that I was not able to accomplish my original idea..."_ Well, there was a suggestion to see if **other** css was applied... You did not report back on that so that is up to you. And if  `<inputTextarea readonly="true" />` works and `<h:inputTextarea value="#{f.text}" style="white-space: pre-wrap" readonly="true"/>` does not, that is strange...

Comment: I abbreviated the line in my comment, your's is the complete line. Sorry for the confusion! About the **other** css: I could not find anything that would interfere.

Comment: If it did not work, there 100% must be something that interferes... But since I don't have any richfaces project at hand, nor do I have the time  (or need/urge/wish) to create one, I can unfortunately no help any further