# How to skip rendering images in Jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a html string which contains images and text. While rendering, I only want to render the text and not the images.

I tried to do this :

`<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{fn:replace(answerBlock.content,'&lt;img&gt;','')}" />`

but this returned a malformed html which then rendered on the screen .

How can I skip the img tags and just render the text in jsf ?

Answer (score 5):

Do not use string or regex functions to manipulate user-controlled HTML. The risk for a XSS attack hole is in this particular example very big as not all aspects are covered (e.g. `<script>`, `onclick`, etc). Just use a real HTML parser which is aware of XSS implications. For example [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) which has also a [whitelist sanitizer feature](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer).

```
String sanitizedHtml = Jsoup.clean(dirtyHtml, Whitelist.basic());
```

Then display that instead:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.sanitizedHtml}" escape="false" />
```

To improve performance, consider parsing it only once and saving in DB along with raw data.

#### See also:

- [How to implement a possibility for user to post some html-formatted data in a safe way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410526/how-to-implement-a-possibility-for-user-to-post-some-html-formatted-data-in-a-sa/)
- [CSRF, XSS and SQL Injection attack prevention in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf)

Answer (score 0):

I would add code to your `answerBlock` bean.  Something like:

```
public String imageStrippedContent() {
    return stripImgTags( content() );
}

private String stripImgTags( String html ) {
    // strip img tag using dom parser like jtidy, or maybe regex
    ...
}
```

Then modify your facelet to:

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{answerBlock.imageStrippedContent} />
```