# Checking "\n" or some other special characters character in rendered attribute

Tags: jsf

I have a property which can possibly contain `\n` characters. I would like to check in the `rendered` attribute of a JSF component if the property contains `\n` and if so, then don't render the component. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the functional requirement for which you thought that this is the right solution? What exactly do you want to do with this information?

Comment: i am using
<tr:group rendered="#{not empty arg.value and not empty fn:replace(arg.csops,'\\n','') }" escape="false">

Comment: Okay, I clarified the question. How exactly does your current attempt fail? Seems it should work fine. Still, it would be interesting to know why exactly you don't want to render. I can't think of real world appliances for this check so perhaps you're still looking in the wrong direction for the solution.

Comment: its not working. its giving a null pointer exception error..

Comment: Apparently `#{arg.csops}` is `null`. Wouldn't it make sense to just check `not empty arg.csops` beforehand?

Comment: actually the values is saved as null in database, but its coming as "\n\n" value in the service side.

Comment: Ah, you're redisplaying input retrieved from a `<textarea>` which was submitted with only 2 newlines? Just perform a `String#trim()` or `fn:trim()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *actually the values is saved as null in database, but its coming as "\n\n" value in the service side.*

Provided that you mean that the `\n` represents the sole value, then you can use `fn:trim()` for that.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.value}" rendered="#{not empty fn:trim(bean.value)}" />
```

Alternatively, create a converter which immediately trims the submitted value before the model get polluted with unwanted characters:

```
<h:inputTextarea value="#{bean.value}" converter="trimConverter" />
```

```java
@FacesConverter("trimConverter")
public class TrimConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        String trimmed = (submittedValue != null) ? submittedValue.trim() : null;
        return (trimmed == null || trimmed.isEmpty()) ? null : trimmed;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
        return (modelValue != null) ? modelValue.toString() : "";
    }

}
```

and then just do

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.value}" rendered="#{not empty bean.value}" />
```

By the way, in the comments you specified `escape="false"`. If this input is coming from an enduser via `<textarea>`, be aware that you're opening a huge XSS attack hole here. See also [How to implement a possibility for user to post some html-formatted data in a safe way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410526/how-to-implement-a-possibility-for-user-to-post-some-html-formatted-data-in-a-sa/)