# Form security by replacing '>', '<' characters

Tags: security, jsp

i create a web form with JSP, and for preventing attacks I do the following:

```
input.replace("<", "something else");
input.replace(">", "something else");
```

so a user cannot add HTML or other tags inside a form.

Is this enough to prevent attacks of this kind(Insertions of HTML or other tags inside
my website)??

Thanks you
JH. G.

Comment: What if someone then fills in `&lt;script&gt;alert('got you!')&lt;/script&gt;` so they can attack the system that gets this data AFTER yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no. I recommend that you should checkout the [ESAPI](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Enterprise_Security_API) project for this.  They have built in tools to HTML encode requests and responses as to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: Why no? Could you give me an example of an attack?

Comment: Sure.  Checkout http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html for a good cheatsheet on the list of XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not entirely the right way. It's not only incomplete as `'`, `"` and `&` [also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) needs to be escaped, but you should actually be using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:out>` or `fn:escapeXml()` to escape HTML/XML entities in the view side.

E.g.

```
<c:out value="${bean.value}" />
<input type="text" name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}" />
```

#### See also:

- [XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java/2658941#2658941)