# Redisplay submitted value in input field

Tags: jsp, input

I have search functionality in my jsp page.. When user types "abc" and search for that. I get the result back but is there a way to retrieve that abc back to that search textbox along with the search results? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just prefill the input value with the submitted value. Submitted input values are available in EL via the `${param}` request parameter map keyed by input field names.

```html
<input type="text" name="query" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.query)}" />
```

Note the importance of [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `fn:escapeXml()`. It's to prevent your page from [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) [attacks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) while redisplaying user-controlled input.

The above example will prefill the input value with the result of `request.getParameter("query")`. As [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) is null-safe, it won't display anything if it returns `null`.

#### See also:

- [XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="${param.foo}" />
```

This will also work if you want something more basic, but I am not sure about the security