# Render HTML unescaped in a JSP page

Tags: html, jsp

I've a field on a DB that contains an HTML text and I need to print it into a JSP page. How can I render the HTML? Using `<c:out value="${text}" />` I can see the text with HTML tags. In other words, it is escaping the HTML.

Comment: what do you mena by parse it? you wish to render it as html?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<c:out>` by default escapes XML entities `<`, `>`, `&`, `"` and `'` to prevent XSS attacks.

So to solve your problem, either just don't use `<c:out>` (works on JSP 2.0 and newer):

```
${text}
```

or add the `escapeXml="false" attribute`:

```html
<c:out value="${text}" escapeXml="false" />
```

You only need to ensure that this HTML is trusted, or this will be a very easy [XSS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) hole. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) may be helpful in this, see also [XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application).