# security functions

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Does Java have standard functions for security like in php `htmlspecialchars`, `strip_tags`? Or must I write my own functions? I want to be sure my script handles user data safely.

Comment: Related: [XSS prevention in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly.

Protection against injection attacks in Java comes "for free" **provided** that you do certain things the right way.  For example:

- Don't create SQL by concatenating strings.  Instead, create your SQL with placeholders, and compile / execute using JDBC `PreparedStatement`.
- In JSPs, use `<c:out>` to output any data that comes from the user.  This automatically HTML escapes it to denature any potential injected nasties.

Comment: i use all things that you type, but data comes from input form by user. If i use PreparedStatement for example, befor adding record to my databese it will check my data? So i don`t need to use such functions on my request parameters, which comes from client?

Comment: It doesn't check the data *per se*.  Rather it causes the parameter containing the user's input to be treated as a single SQL data value ... irrespective of any funky quoting, etc that the user might attempt to use in an SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

you can try spring security library (.jar)
which gives all the features to avoid web related security issues

here is the link
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/

you can also find some help from the owasp.com site
http://owasp.com/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score -1):

This is not a solution, just an advice, when its about security, i never use built in functions, i always write them myself according to client requirements, use RegExp, they are very powerful for this.

Comment: it's too troublesome, there is no some easy way to do this?

Comment: It is also bad advice, unless you are better at security than everyone else.  (And there is a difference between *thinking* you are better than actually *being* better.)

Comment: Stephen, why would this be a bad advice? you mean that writing your own function is a bad advice? in comparison to use a built in function where you can only see but not edit the source code?