# How to regex-replace all occurrences of ${...} by <c:out value="${...}" />

Tags: java, html, regex

I have unprotected JSPs which have XSS holes. I need to replace all `${...}` strings which are not *already* inside a `<c:out value="${...}" />` tag by a `<c:out value="${...}" />`.

For example,

```html
<select>
   <option value="${foo}">label</option>
</select>    
${bar}
<c:out value="${message}" />
```

needs to be regex-replaced to the following:

```html
<select>
   <option value="<c:out value="${foo}" />">label</option>
</select>    
<c:out value="${bar}" />
<c:out value="${message}" />
```

Comment: Usually it's quite reverse - <c:out is to be replaced with less verbose ${...}. How is this related to XSS?

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky Using `<c:out ...` is best practice, particularly if you don't have full control of what that variable contains. It will escape XML to prevent XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Eugene: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java/2658941#2658941 Perhaps you're confusing JSP with its successor Facelets. EL in template text is then indeed implicitly escaped.

Comment: So it might be actual only for user-controlled-content. Which is not usually the case when any user input is cleared from any HTML tags.

Comment: @Eugene: indeed, for user-controlled input only. Escaping/sanitizing them on input is **not** the right way. You end up with possibly unreusable data which cannot be used in PDFs/CSV/XML/XLS/etc, or unrecoverable mistakes which can only be rectified by having original data, or double-escaping when the website is completely redesigned to (automatically) perform proper escaping. It should be escaped on output only.

Comment: For example, if that is a comment on a web-site - then what issues can be with sanitizing on input? What could be a purpose of `<script>` tag in PDF, CSV etc. Also it's easier to control a single input point, than many output ones. Of course, there could be exceptions but in general it's a right solution, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your starting text has a mixture of `<c:out value="${...}" />` and `${...}` in it. If that's the case, you could try something like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll(
             "(?:<c:out\\s+value=\")?\\$\\{([^}]*)\\}(?:\"\\s*/>)?", 
             "<c:out value=\"\\${$1}\" />"
      );
```

I'm a little rusty on my Java regex syntax, so check that I have the backslashes right. Otherwise, I think that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not the tool to use when requiring context. However, it would be simple enough to do in two steps by first replacing all instances of `<c:out value="${...}" />` to `${...}` and then all `${...}` to `<c:out value="${...}" />`.

Regular expressions

```
\${[^}]+}
<c:out value="\${[^}]+}" />
```