# In jsp a request parameter (a string value with white spaces)displayed only upto the first whitespace in text box

Tags: jsp

```
<input type="text" name="designation" value=<%=request.getParameter("designation")%> ></input>
```

In this JSP, I've send request parameters from an another JSP page via javascript using window.location.replace() function.

I want to display that request parameter in this jsp page in a text-box.

But its showing only a part of the string up to the first white-space only. remaining string is got trimmed.

What might be the cause of this problem?

e.g. if designation="software engineer" then it is displaying in the text box only "software", and not " "(space) and "engineer"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to surround the attribute value with quotes.

```html
<input type="text" name="designation" value="<%=request.getParameter("designation")%>">
```

Otherwise the space will just be interpreted as HTML element attribute separator and the next word becomes then another HTML element attribute.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, if you use this approach throughout your JSPs, also for redisplaying user-controlled data from DBs, then you've a [XSS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) hole. Make sure that you HTML-escape them properly. See also [XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java).

Comment: Thank you for your reply..Oh now, I'm getting values correctly with spaces too. I didn't know to include them in double quotes. That's great.. Thanks a lot.!!