# Replace "\n" in EL

Tags: jsp, el

In a JSP file I wanto to replace newlines (`\n`) with `<br />`. I tried

```
${fn:replace(someString, '\n', '<br />')}
```

But I get an error `'\n' ecnountered, was expeting one of...`

Which I guess it means the parser doesn't like something like this.

Is it possible to do something like this using EL?

Comment: Found workaround
`<% pageContext.setAttribute("newLine", "\n"); %>
${fn:replace(someString, newLine, '<br />')}`

Comment: Sorry, please look at my edited demo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create an EL function for that.

First create a static method which does the desired job:

```
package com.example;

public final class Functions {
     private Functions() {}

     public static String nl2br(String string) {
         return (string != null) ? string.replace("\n", "<br/>") : null;
     }
}
```

Then create a `/WEB-INF/functions.tld` which look like follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>Custom_Functions</short-name>
    <uri>http://example.com/functions</uri>

    <function>
        <name>nl2br</name>
        <function-class>com.example.Functions</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String nl2br(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Finally use it as follows:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://example.com/functions" prefix="f" %>
...
${f:nl2br(someString)}
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: I tried to use with <c:set var="test" value="${f:nl2br(someString)}"/> but didn't work. How can i do this suppose i need to use <c:set.. ?

Comment: @Doni: Just press "Ask Question" and post an SSCCE.

Comment: I have used escapeXml=false otherwise it print to screen still the <br/>...example: <c:out escapeXml="false" value="${f:nl2br(someString)}"/>

Comment: @user3410465: just don't use `<c:out>` at all. Simply do `${f:nl2br(someString)}`. This is only not supported in JSP 1.x, but as JSP 2.0 was released more than a decade ago, no one would expect one being still on JSP 1.x these days.

Comment: @BalusC Be aware that you risk xss vulnerabilities without `<c:out>`, if for instance `someString` is a user input. I suggest processing the string with `<c:out>` and then passing the result to `f:nlbr()`.

Comment: @fishbone: That's correct. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2658922 for better alternatives in case this is really user-controlled input.

Answer (score 2):

Your way is a lot easier. Why didn't I think of that.  Here is a demo page.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<c:set var="newLine" value="\n" />
<c:set var="myText" value="one\ntwo\nthree" />
${fn:replace(myText, newLine, '<br/>')}
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but this is not good, it will need to URL decode it before printing, otherwise it would print %XX instead of spaces, accented letters etc.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked by first defining a variable `newLine`, either with

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("newLine", "\n"); %>
```

Or

```
<c:set var="newLine" value="<%= '\n' %>" />
```

And then

```
${fn:replace(someString, newLine, '<br/>')}
```