# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string in JSP Page

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, jstl

Hi can someone please help why this is giving an error when trying to display the values in a JSP page. I don't have any number been converted or String been converted to Number, however I get NumberFormatException

my Servlet getting the request to display a user record

```
if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("update")){
        System.out.println("Came into Update");
        userId=(int) Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userid"));
        nbId=request.getParameter("nbId").trim();
        System.out.println("User iD and NBid: "+ userId + nbId);

        User user=new User();
        user.setUser_id(userId);
        user.setUser_nbk(nbId);



        List userRecords=UserDAO.getUserRecord(user);
        request.setAttribute("userRecords", userRecords);
        List owningOrg=Owning_Org_DB.getOwningOrgRecords();
        request.setAttribute("owningOrg", owningOrg);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/JSP/TableMaintenance/UserNewAdd.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

POJO:

```
 @Entity
 @Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
  public class User {

@Id
private int user_id;
private String user_first_name;
private String user_middle_name;
private String user_last_name;

       //getters and setters methos
   }
```

DAO:

```
public static List getUserRecord(User obj){

    Logger lo=LoggerFactory.getLogger("UserDAO.getUserRecord");
    Session session= Annotationsessionfactory.getAnnotationSession();
    Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();

    lo.debug("Request for A user Record");
    //List<User> recList=new ArrayList<User>();
    List recList=null;
    try{

        //String userRecord="from User";
        Criteria userList=session.createCriteria(User.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("user_nbk", obj.getUser_nbk()))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("user_id", obj.getUser_id()));



         recList=userList.list();
        System.out.println(recList.size());

    }catch (Exception e){

        lo.info("Exception Occured in UserDAO.getUserRecord");
        lo.debug("Exception Occured in UserDAO.getUserRecord:"+e);
        tx.rollback();

    }finally{

        session.close();

        lo.info("Session Closed in UserDAO.userRecordslist finally block: ");
    }

    lo.debug("Record was sent to the requesting servlet or method: "+ recList);
    return recList;

}
```

JSP Page

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>First Name</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" maxlength="80" value="">${userRecords.user_first_name}</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Middle Name</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="middlename" name="middlename" maxlength="80" value="${userRecords.user_middle_name}"></td>

.......
```

Exception I get:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
**java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "user_first_name"**
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:447)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)
at javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:166)
at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:51)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:938)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.JSP.TableMaintenance.UserNewAdd_jsp._jspService    (UserNewAdd_jsp.java:77)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at com.servicedbUpdate.UserUpdateDB_NewAdds.doPost(UserUpdateDB_NewAdds.java:79)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Feb 13, 2013 10:30:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet UserUpdateDB_NewAdds threw exception
       **java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "user_first_name"**
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:447)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)
at javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:166)
at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:51)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:938)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.JSP.TableMaintenance.UserNewAdd_jsp._jspService(UserNewAdd_jsp.java:77)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at com.servicedbUpdate.UserUpdateDB_NewAdds.doPost(UserUpdateDB_NewAdds.java:79)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userid"))` is in your code.

Comment: but that is not giving me any error..i was able to place it in User object without any error and Hibernate has pulled the record (I checked size of the list). Error is occurring when the request is going into JSP page.

Comment: userRecords is a list of users, you need to iterate through the userRecords to get to each user

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `${userRecords}` here

```
${userRecords.user_first_name}
${userRecords.user_middle_name}
```

is a `List<User>`, however you're attempting to access it as if it's a single `User`. This is not valid. In EL, a `List` can only be accessed with an integer index, indicating the position of the list item you'd like to access, like so

```
${userRecords[0].user_first_name}
${userRecords[0].user_middle_name}
```

The exception is also basically telling that it expected an integer value instead of a string value. If you look closer at the stack trace, you'll see that a `ListELResolver` is involved.

However, your concrete problem is bigger. You should actually be iterating over the list. Use the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:forEach>` for that. E.g. (simplified from your odd code snippet):

```html
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${userRecords}" var="user">
        <tr>
            <td>${user.user_first_name}</td>
            <td>${user.user_middle_name}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

*(note: keep the [XSS attack hole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java/2658941#2658941) in mind if you really intend to redisplay them as input values)*

By the way, I'd work on your [Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). Those underscores are really not Java-ish.

Answer (score 0):

Check what your function/DAO is returning.  In my case, my HQL was returning some default value because I had a query without "select" and with a join as in "from EmailTemplate et join EmailTemplateParts etp"