# NumberFormatException when iterating over list JAVA

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to iterate over a list but it does not work. It is a basic operation but i can not find the problem.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("home");
    UserModel user = sm.get(request);
    mav.addObject("user", user);
    try {
        List<ArticleModel> articles = articleDao.listFiveArticles();
        mav.addObject("articles", articles);
        return mav;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return mav;
    }

}
```

And i am trying to iterate overarticles list in jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<jsp:include page="menu.jsp" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Начало</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:if test="${not empty articles}">
        <c:forEach var="a" items="${articles}">
            <p>
                <b>${a.article_name}</b>
            </p>
            <p>${a.article_body}</p>
            <p>
                <i>Публикувал:</i> <a
                    href="<c:url value="/all-articles?name="/>${a.article_author}">${a.article_author}</a>
            </p>
            <hr>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

but i have this exception

**EDIT:** This is the full stacktrace. I debug and check the articles list. It is not empty for sure!

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "article_name"
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:144)
    javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:61)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:944)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(home_jsp.java:221)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(home_jsp.java:182)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:141)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: That's pretty straight forward. What have you done to debug this?

Comment: Show the full stacktrace.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803379/exception-numberformatexception-for-input-string-in-jsp-list-page