# How to read specific column data with count?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to read specific column data with count using hibernate.

Here is my SQL query

```
select current_state,count(current_state) from cssaction group by current_state
```

It is working well when i'm executing in workbench editor

Output:

[image]

When  i'm executing same query though Session in hibernate then i'm getting exception.

Code:

```
List<Object[]> resultList = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().
createQuery("select currentState,count(currentState) from CssAction group by currentState").getResultList();
```

Exception:

```
May 18, 2017 4:19:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
May 18, 2017 4:19:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "CLOSED"
May 18, 2017 4:19:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/Test] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "CLOSED"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.io.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeDouble(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:222)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.io.StringConverter.createFromBytes(StringConverter.java:104)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.io.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeByteArray(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:232)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:124)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:225)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.ByteArrayRow.getValue(ByteArrayRow.java:84)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getNonStringValueFromRow(ResultSetImpl.java:630)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:829)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:847)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getInt(NewProxyResultSet.java:2677)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$OrdinalEnumValueMapper.getValue(EnumType.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultRow(QueryLoader.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(QueryLoader.java:436)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:769)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:985)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:943)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1481)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1441)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
```

Comment: Are you sure exception occured on given code? Maybe you are parsing object array incorrectly.

Comment: yeah i'm sure. i inspected right part of that statement when i was debugging. thank you..:)

Comment: can you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27823276/4144381

Comment: @Arif Ulusoy thanks for you response. my issue resolved.