# How to change servlet request body in java filter?

Tags: java, servlets, xss, servlet-filters

How can I change request body in java filter to protect from `XSS` attack?
I build `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and use `getparameter` for change body but
get stream close exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698381/how-to-perform-output-encoding-using-filter-to-prevent-xss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### XSSFilter.java

```
public class XSSFilter implements Filter {


@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    XSSRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new XSSRequestWrapper(
            (HttpServletRequest) request);

    String body = IOUtils.toString(wrappedRequest.getReader());


    if(!"".equals(body))
    {
        JSONObject oldJsonObject = new JSONObject(body);
        JSONObject newJsonObject = new JSONObject();

        for(String key : oldJsonObject.keySet())
        {
            newJsonObject.put(key, XSSUtils.stripXSS(oldJsonObject.get(key).toString()));
        }
        wrappedRequest.resetInputStream(newJsonObject.toString().getBytes());

    }


    chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, response);
 }
}
```

### XSSRequestWrapper .java

```
public class XSSRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {


private byte[] rawData;
private HttpServletRequest request;
private ResettableServletInputStream servletStream;

public XSSRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
    this.request = request;
    this.servletStream = new ResettableServletInputStream();
}


public void resetInputStream(byte[] newRawData) {
    servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(newRawData);
}

@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    if (rawData == null) {
        rawData = IOUtils.toByteArray(this.request.getReader());
        servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData);
    }
    return servletStream;
}

@Override
public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
    if (rawData == null) {
        rawData = IOUtils.toByteArray(this.request.getReader());
        servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData);
    }
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(servletStream));
}

private class ResettableServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {

    private InputStream stream;

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return stream.read();
     }
   }
 }
```

### XSSUtils .java

```
public class XSSUtils {

private XSSUtils()
{

}

public static String stripXSS(String value) {
    return value == null ? value : escapeHtml4(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not actually working. 
Filter is called, but body still the original one, methods getInputStream and getReader, haven't called

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have enough reputation to add a comment, I am adding it as an answer. After 3 years, I found the accepted answer to save me hours. At the same time, I had to fix couple of things, and hence adding...

(1) A bug (missing assignment to rawData)

```
public void resetInputStream(byte[] newRawData) {
    rawData = newRawData;
    servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(newRawData);
}
```

(2) A change necessitated over time. Reference:
[HttpServletRequestWrapper, example implementation for setReadListener / isFinished / isReady?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208456/httpservletrequestwrapper-example-implementation-for-setreadlistener-isfinish)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take your time and read Help section on [Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering). "Since I do not have enough reputation to add a comment" - it's not a tragedy, karma will come to you, remember old motto: "lurk more"