# Using for loop inside of a JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, loops, for-loop

I want to loop through an *ArrayList* of "Festivals" and get their information with *get* methods, printing out all its values. For some reason when I use this code, it will always choose the "0"th value and not increment the loop.

If I hard code the values as "get(1)" it will get the correct values so my issue is clearly with the syntax.

```
<h1>All Festival Information</h1>
    <jsp:useBean id="allFestivals" type="java.util.ArrayList" scope="session" />
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Festival Name:</td>
            <td>Location:</td>
            <td>Start Date:</td>
            <td>End Date:</td>
            <td>URL:</td>
        </tr>
        <% for(int i = 0; i < allFestivals.size(); i+=1) { %>
            <tr>      
                <td>${allFestivals.get(i).getFestivalName()}</td>
                <td>${allFestivals.get(i).getLocation()}</td>
                <td>${allFestivals.get(i).getStartDate()}</td>
                <td>${allFestivals.get(i).getEndDate()}</td>
                <td>${allFestivals.get(i).getURL()}</td>  
            </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
```

Comment: Writing Java code inside JSP page is not recommended. Use JSTL core tag `<c:forEach>` instead.

Comment: Just stop using `<% %>`. You'll automatically be forced to do the right things. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You concrete problem is caused because you're mixing [discouraged and old school](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) *scriptlets* `<% %>` with its successor EL `${}`. They do not share the same variable scope. The `allFestivals` is not available in *scriptlet* scope and the `i` is not available in EL scope.

You should install [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) (<-- click the link for instructions) and declare it in top of JSP as follows:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

and then iterate over the list as follows:

```html
<c:forEach items="${allFestivals}" var="festival">
    <tr>      
        <td>${festival.festivalName}</td>
        <td>${festival.location}</td>
        <td>${festival.startDate}</td>
        <td>${festival.endDate}</td>
        <td>${festival.URL}</td>  
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

*(beware of possible [XSS attack holes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java), use `<c:out>` accordingly)*

Don't forget to **remove** the `<jsp:useBean>` as it has no utter value here when you're using a servlet as model-and-view controller. It would only lead to confusion. See also [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). Further you would do yourself a favour to disable *scriptlets* by the following entry in `web.xml` so that you won't accidently use them:

```xml
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Not sure why I was told to use the "<% %>" as most information on-line conforms to your method using "<c". Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps you were relying on a resource which is more than a decade old.

Comment: if you want to get the index of the list like me, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18826043/926460

Comment: "My university. Talk about a bit old school teaching" -- I'm taking a class on this now. It's 2016 and we're being taught techniques that were bad practice over a decade ago. It's amazing what lingers on with some profs ...

Answer (score 22):

Do this

```
    <% for(int i = 0; i < allFestivals.size(); i+=1) { %>
        <tr>      
            <td><%=allFestivals.get(i).getFestivalName()%></td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
```

Better way is to use c:foreach see link [jstl for each](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm)

Comment: In OP's particular case, `allFestivals` is not available in *scriptlet* scope.