# How to get a index value from foreach loop in jstl

Tags: java, jsp, for-loop, foreach, jstl

I have a value set in the `request` object like the following,

```
String[] categoriesList=null;
categoriesList = engine.getCategoryNamesArray();
request.setAttribute("categoriesList", categoriesList );
```

and this is how I iterate in jsp page

```
<% if(request.getAttribute("categoriesList") != null) { %>
<c:forEach var="categoryName" items="${categoriesList}">
   <li><a onclick="getCategoryIndex()" href="#">${categoryName}</a></li>
</c:forEach>
<% }%>
```

How do I get index of each element and pass it to JavaScript function `onclick="getCategoryIndex()"`.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

use [varStatus](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) to get the index  [c:forEach varStatus properties](http://www.bmchild.com/2012/03/jstl-cforeach-varstatus-properties.html)

```
<c:forEach var="categoryName" items="${categoriesList}" varStatus="loop">
    <li><a onclick="getCategoryIndex(${loop.index})" href="#">${categoryName}</a></li>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I get this `Uncaught ReferenceError: `loop is not defined ` and +1 for your effort

Comment: onClick of the element displayed

Comment: Because the varStatus value contains value upto the loop iteration. After that the value is not a valid one. so only you got the exception. For which purpose you need the index

Comment: I need to know the index[location] of each element comes in the String Array.

Comment: it works :) if I do this way onclick="getCategoryIndex(${loop.index})" ...thanks for the help

Comment: if I want to store this loop value in to a variable and pass the same to javascript method than how do I go about ?

Comment: I sued this way `<input type="hidden" id="categoryIndex" name="categoryIndex" value="${category.index}"/>` but it always gives me `0` when do this `var categoryIndex = $('#categoryIndex').val();`

Comment: created new question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827153/jstl-foreach-loop-setting-values-to-a-hidden-variable-returns-zero-always`

Comment: Sorry now only i saw this

Comment: I think the answer is like this: <c:forEach items="${pageScope.names}"
               var="currentName"   varStatus="status">
      Family member #<c:out value="${status.count}" /> is
        <c:out value="${currentName}" /> <br />
    </c:forEach>   Check [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/JSTLForEachStatusCount.htm)

Answer (score 27):

I faced similar problems. After research I understand we have some more options with the `varStatus="loop"`. It can either use a zero based index or one based index:

- The `${loop.index}` uses a 0 base index
- The `${loop.count}` uses a 1 base index

**For Example :**

```
<c:forEach var="currentImage" items="${cityBannerImages}" varStatus="loop">
<picture>
   <source srcset="${currentImage}" media="(min-width: 1000px)"></source>
   <source srcset="${cityMobileImages[loop.count]}" media="(min-width:600px)"></source>
   <img srcset="${cityMobileImages[loop.count]}" alt=""></img>
</picture>
</c:forEach>
```

For more Info please check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html).

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `varStatus` attribute like this:-

```
<c:forEach var="categoryName" items="${categoriesList}" varStatus="myIndex">
```

**myIndex.index** will give you the index. Here `myIndex` is a [LoopTagStatus](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) object.

Hence, you can send that to your javascript method like this:-

```
<a onclick="getCategoryIndex(${myIndex.index})" href="#">${categoryName}</a>
```

Comment: I get this `Uncaught ReferenceError: myIndex is not defined ` and +1 for your effort

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1970" end="2000">
    <option value="${2000-(i-1970)}">${2000-(i-1970)} 
     </option>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="getCategoryIndex(${myIndex.index})" href="#">${categoryName}</a>
```

above line was giving me an error. So I wrote down in below way which is working fine for me.

```
<a onclick="getCategoryIndex('<c:out value="${myIndex.index}"/>')" href="#">${categoryName}</a>
```

Maybe someone else might get same error. Look at this guys!