# jstl : foreach loop setting values to a hidden variable returns zero always

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, foreach, jstl

I have a foreach loop like the following

```
<% if (request.getAttribute("categoriesList") != null) {%>
    <c:forEach var="categoryName" items="${categoriesList}" varStatus="category">
       <input type="hidden" id="categoryIndex" name="categoryIndex" value="${category.index}"/>
       <li><a onclick="getCategoryIndex()" href="#">${categoryName}</a></li>
    </c:forEach>
<% }%>
```

I try to set the index value of item like the following

`<input type="hidden" id="categoryIndex" name="categoryIndex" value="${category.index}"/>`

when I do this

```
var categoryIndex = $('#categoryIndex').val();
console.log("categoryIndex : "+categoryIndex);
```

onClick of listed item it alsways prints `0`

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try it like that:

```
 <c:forEach var="categoryName" items="${categoriesList}" varStatus="category">
   <input type="hidden" id="categoryIndex+${category.index}" name="categoryIndex" value="${category.index}"/>
   <li><a onclick="getCategoryIndex(${category.index})" href="#">${categoryName}</a></li>
 </c:forEach>
```

And in your JavaScript method:

```
 function getCategoryIndex(x){
    var categoryIndex = $('#categoryIndex'+x).val();
    console.log("categoryIndex : "+categoryIndex);
 }
```