# How to get the index of forEach loop in integer

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I want to get the index of forEach loop in integer, I can get it in terms of string i.e

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}" varStatus="loop">
    <c:out value="${loop.index}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

I want to store the value of index in an integer variable, jsp.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825950/how-to-get-a-index-value-from-foreach-loop-in-jstl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a index value from foreach loop in jstl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825950/how-to-get-a-index-value-from-foreach-loop-in-jstl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store it in a variable, it will actually be an integer:

```
<c:set var="index" value="${loop.index}" />
<c:set var="index" value="${index + 1}" />
<c:out value="${index}"/>
```

Should produce `1 2 3` and so on.

Comment: well, I want to store the index in a variable which can be accessed in javascript within the jsp,i need to store it in string or int, The problem being I don't know how to use jstl tags with javascript.

Comment: You have to understand that JSP is executed on the serverside. Just write a JavaScript function like you would do in plain HTML: `<script>someFunction(someVariable)</script>` ... you can also replace `someVariable` with an EL Expression to output the index: `<script>someFunction(${index})</script>` which will result  in `<script>someFunction(2)</script>` for example.