# Table in JSP and how to use jsp -Jstl tag

Tags: jsp-tags

I have displayed one table in jsp page.Now I want a number attached with every row means displayed serial number as first field with every row.The records are dynamic.how I do that?please help me I am new in jsp page

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already.  Welcome to StackOverflow. Feel free to take the [tour]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a index value from foreach loop in jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825950/how-to-get-a-index-value-from-foreach-loop-in-jstl)

Comment: I have a table like below in my jsp page.                                  Packet number | price and one or more field.                         Now i want serial number like this.                                         Serial number | packet number | price .                                   Now that serial number increased with every row .              That data displayed in table is dynamic.some time there are 4 data or 5 data etc.The serial number increased one by one with every row.Started with 1 and end with the last featched data.

Comment: Your comment does not help anyone in answering the question.  Please add a [mcve] of your question by editing it.  Also, refer to our [ask] page for suggestions on how to make this question better.