# How to do a certain task only with the first output of a foreach loop?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I want to output values of a list like this, but also I want to prepend another value to only the first element of the list, i.e. valuesInRow[0]. How do I do this while also outputting the other values in the list without the prepend?

```
<c:forEach var="valuesInRow" items="${valuesInRows}">                                        
  <td>${idPrepend}${valuesInRow}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: You can use `varStatus` to keep track of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use varStatus: [How to get a index value from foreach loop in jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825950/how-to-get-a-index-value-from-foreach-loop-in-jstl)

It will give you some control about the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could get a hold onto the current index, and use aan `if` to check that you are on the first one ?

```
<c:forEach var="valuesInRow" items="${valuesInRows}" varStatus="loop">                                        
  <td><c:if test = "${loop.index == 0}"></c:if>${idPrepend}${valuesInRow}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thank you! I read about it and ended up using when/otherwise but thanks!