# jQuery - append a table to a tr table

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I have in java this two objects:

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String surname;
    List<PersonDetails> details;

    //Constructor and getter-setter methods
    ...
}
```

**PersonDetails.java**

```
public class PersonDetails {
    int age;
    String city;

    //Constructor and getter-setter methods
    ...
}
```

I create a list of Person Object and I put it into the session.

Front-end side I create a table where I display the list:

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
    <tr>        
        <th>Detail</th> <!-- this is a button -->
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr th:each=" p : ${listPerson}">
        <td></td>
        <td>${p.name}</td>
        <td>${p.surname}</td>                                                           
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Like you can see there is no trace of the details list for each p in the table. Because, I would that, when I click on the detail button, a new table containing details list was appended to that row (p).

Like this:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [falafel.com](https://blog.falafel.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Hierarchical-Kendo-UI-Grid-_-Kendo-UI-Web.png))</sub>

**I'm not asking you to produce the code**, I'm asking some ideas to do this. There is any plugin for this case?

Answer (score 0):

It is a div not a tr.

Let me try to draw:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to append a new `table` you might have to insert a whole new row with a `td` spanning the preceding `row`'s columns. Doing this might not be the greatest solution for someone using a screenreader, though. You'd probably have use a lot of offscreen text and ARIA to associate the data in the nested details table to each person.

How about opening the details in a dialog/modal instead of appending a new `table`? Opening the details in a dialog/modal would be better for keyboard navigation and associating the details to each person.

I think it's better to keep all of the top level data in one `table`. This is what tables should be used for—tabular data. Breaking up the data for display purposes disjoins the data, which is also not great for accessibility. Opening up the details in a separate `table` dialog/modal keeps the data and HTML structure simple.

Comment: I can't use the modal, because the client wants a new table for the details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using tables, this is the approach you should use:

[image: Structure]

You should generate 2 rows for each record, one containing the data and other containing the details.

In order to make it simple, the second row could be have a `colspan` of the size of the "parent" table and the content inside it should be wrapped in a `<div>`.

When you click on the respective arrow, the row right bellow should be shown.
In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deLecq9d/) there is an example of how to do this.

Comment: How can I generate two row for each record? Currently I put the for each in the `<tr  th:each=" view_Object : ${consultaPagamentiForm.listaDecretoMassivo}">`.

Comment: I don't know the first thing about JSP, but a quick search here on SO took me to [this anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15839540/1798341). You have to iterate over the two lists (one with the "parent" record and the other with the "childs") an generate a row for each one.