# Collection is not in scope of jsp file (Spring MVC, ModelAndView)

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, modelandview

Usually i can find solution provided by StackOverflow community in older questions. This time my brain stopped working, i guess...

All I'm trying to do is show a list of customers which I'm taking out of MySQL database. Everything is going fine, but when i'm passing the **List** from controller to view I can't use it in jsp file, as it appears to be out of scope(?).

If you could suggest any solutions / links / tutorials i would be really thankful

**CustomerDAO:**

```
public List<Customer> getAllCustomers()
    {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("library-manager");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        
        TypedQuery<Customer> query = entityManager.createQuery("select e from Customer e", Customer.class);
        List<Customer> customers = query.getResultList();
        
        entityManager.close();      
        entityManagerFactory.close();
        
        return customers;
    }
```

**CustomersController:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllCustomers")
    public ModelAndView getAllCustomers(){
        
        List<Customer> customers = customerDAO.getAllCustomers();
        
        return new ModelAndView("getAllCustomers", "customersList", customers);
    }
```

At this point I have no clue how to access this List in my jsp file (getAllCustomers.jsp).
When I try to access it in Java block <% %>, then I get simple errors like:

> "customers cannot be resolved to a variable"

**getAllCustomers.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="db_objects.Customer" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>List of all customers:</h2>
<%
for(Customer customer : customers){
    out.println(customer.getCustomerFirstName);
    out.println(customer.getCustomerLastName);
    out.println(customer.getCustomerContactNumber);
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope you will find some patience to help me a little bit here :)

## edit

I got some information that my question may be the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839335/using-for-loop-inside-of-a-jsp)

I'm not sure if it's automatic system or not, but my question is not how to use for loop but how to pass a collection to jsp via ModelAndView.

## edit2

I just figured it out what @RamPrakash meant. I will try his solution tomorrow.
But until then, maybe someone from different timezone could answer if using scriptlet instead of JSTL may cause that problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839335/using-for-loop-inside-of-a-jsp

Comment: @RamPrakash Thanks a lot! I will try using JSTL tomorrow, i hope it will help. I'll let u know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `jsp` you are referring to the customers list by `customers`. This however is only a valid identifier in the context of the `getAllCustomers` method of your controller.

Try `customersList` instead and consult the JavaDoc of the [`ModelAndView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#ModelAndView-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Thanks @hotzst. I tried your solution (my mistake was so obvious there, I dont know how i didn't notice that.)
For some reason it stil doesn't work. I get the same error when I used 'customersList'.
I'm not sure but it looks like some error with ModelAndView, looks like jsp "is not aware" that 'customersList' is being passed to it.

I will give it a try tomorrow, thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: That solution helped me with little assistance of solution proposed by RamPrakesh in comment to main post.