# AngularJS an Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a jsp page and i use AngularJs to loop and populate the page

```
<div ng-repeat="w in weatherData track by $index"
            ng-click="displayWeatherDetail(w.name)"
            class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item ">
            <div class="card portfolio-link ">
                <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"
                    href="#portfolioModal6">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div> <img class="img-fluid"
                    src="resources/img/portfolio/06-thumbnail.jpg" alt="City image">
                </a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 id="test" class="card-title">{{w.name}}</h3>
                    <p class="card-text ">
                        {{w.description}} <span><img src="{{w.icon}}" /></span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="card-text text-muted">
                        Maxumum Temprature: {{w.temp}} &deg C <br> Minimum
                        Temprature: {{w.minTemp}} &deg C <br> Humidity:
                        {{w.humidity}} &deg C
                    </p>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

With jquery i want to retrieve the H3 element inside the `card-body` element with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert($("#test").val());
});
```

I get as result undefined. If i try with `text()` i get empty text. Seems like that jquery runs before angularJs finish to populate the view. What i'm trying to accomplish is. I got a lot of city to display, angular take city names and information from my server, with the city name i want to contact google image api to retrieve an image of that city and add it an image inside the previous generated card.

Comment: Ids have to be _unique_

Comment: Why do you need to do this?? Just access your own variable `w.name`. There may be several of these so you would have to know which one you wanted. But `$scope.weatherData[x].name` will give you want you want.

Comment: @Intervalia how? can you post some code example?

Comment: h3 doesn't have value as it's not an input

Comment: @Andreas the id "test" is unique

Comment: but with angular you don't need to use jquery.. just get it within your scope

Comment: It's not unique if you're using ng-repeat

Comment: @Phiter ahh i see know does ng-repeat assign the "test" id on each element? Can you provide some link because i'm still learning

Answer (score 0):

Since IDs should be unique select based upon the class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($(".card-title").val());
    });
```

Comment: I got undefined

Comment: I think it might because the jquery ready event is firing before angular is finished rendering.  A way to test this is to set a timer delay.

`$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function () { alert($(".card-title").val()); }, 5000);
    });`

Answer (score 0):

This work :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        alert("Value: " + $("#test").text());

});
```

But use JSP with Angular is a big error...

Answer (score 0):

here is an advice use jsp or angular but not them both in same time, 
1)the decision for angular contact google image api after data has been loaded from your server like `ajaxRequest((weatherData)=>{/*loop weatherData and contact to google*/})`, 
or 2)you can build a html page with jsp like here [Using for loop inside of a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839335/using-for-loop-inside-of-a-jsp) than your jquery will return the value for your last id

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i appreciate.

Comment: if you don\`t want change your realization, check until angular will create dom then extract the value from it,  you could try
let ites =0,_inter = setInterval(()=>{
  if($("#test").text() || ites++ >10)clearInterval(_inter);     console.log($("#test").text() )
},100)

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs performed after the document.ready so using jquery the elements are undefined. To fix this problem i used the directives as showed in [ng-repeat finish event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/ng-repeat-finish-event)