# Image tag value scr double white space in path

Tags: html, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets

In my jsp page in tag (`img src="upload/<%=a.getUrlimmagine()%>"`) i have this error

`Bad value in "upload/ " for attribute "src" on element "img":DOUBLE_WHITE SPACE in PATH`

How can I solve it?

Comment: You need to substitute spaces for `%20`.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Just posted an answer :)

Comment: you have deleted the answer Thi is the error in netbeans http://postimg.org/image/4evqi8afp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because URLs should not have spaces (see : [Are URLs allowed to have a space in them?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/497972/696299)
) you should encode your url so the unsafe characters will be replaced with some strings representing them (i.e. space becoming `%20`)

So you either do this in the `getUrlimmagine()` in your bean or do the encoding in the jsp page.

If you are sure that the only unsafe charcter in your image names is spaces so you can use [`String.replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) in the backing bean or use the JSTL [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/replace.fn.html) function h in your jsp page

otherwise if you want the cleanest solution, you should definitely read this article : [What every web developer must know about URL encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding) by Stéphane Épardaud

A cleaner solution to get the same result without using JSP expression is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084905/how-to-mix-href-within-jstl-code/18085207#18085207) by [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)

Comment: The problem is "upload/<%=a.getUrlimmagine()%>"  is seen as "upload/ ".Namely <%=a.getUrlimmagine()%> is for html a white space

Comment: When in debug ,what is the value returned by `getUrlimmagine()` ?

you can also check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18085207/696299 
it's more clean that using JSP expression

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the replaceAll method for String:

```
<img src="upload/<%=a.getUrlimmagine().replaceAll(" ", "%20")%>" />
```

Comment: The problem is "upload/<%=a.getUrlimmagine()%>" is seen as "upload/ ".Namely <%=a.getUrlimmagine()%> is for html a white space.
This is th error in netbeans http://postimg.org/image/4evqi8afp/

Comment: I guess for netbeans you might need the EL ${} syntax rather than scriptlets (<%=%>).

Comment: Dude you're a spammer. That image is not a netbeans error.

Comment: Why spammer?This is the image that show error in netbeans