# Are there any drawbacks of using JSTL tags for escaping XML for XSS prevention

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I want to sanitize the text which will be sent to user (browser) by the server using these jsp tags.

got idea after reading this post [XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java)

```
<c:out value="${bean.userControlledValue}">
<input name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}">
```

But I have many jsp pages and I want to perform search for tags or `<p>` and add these escaping tags so, Is it good to do this or is any drawback or precaution we need to care of.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any drawbacks or precautions to care of.
If you want to be sure, the best is to read the actual source code :)
[org.apache.taglibs.standard.functions.Functions](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/taglibs/standard/1.1.2/org/apache/taglibs/standard/functions/Functions.java#Functions.escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29)