# Read data sent from ajax to jsp page using jstl

Tags: ajax, jsp, jstl

I have an ajax call to a jsp page with certain data.

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",

    url: "jsp/order.jsp",
    data: {
        "dishId"                    :   id,
        "dishPrice"                 :   price,
        "dishName"                  :   name

          },
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
          }
    });
```

I want to read the data in the order.jsp using jstl. However I am not able to do that using the following statements.

```
<c:out value='${dishName}' />
<c:out value='${dishId}' />
```

I know it can be done using scriptlets but wanted to do it using jstl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All HTTP request parameters are in EL available via implicit `${param}` mapping.

So, this should do:

```
<c:out value="${param.dishName}" />
<c:out value="${param.dishId}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE 5 tutorial - Expression Language - Implicit Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, do note that there's quite a difference between "[JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)" and "[EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)". Those `<c:xxx>` things are JSTL tags. Those `${...}` things is EL. You can also use EL standalone:

```
${param.dishName}
${param.dishId}
```

However, that opens a potential [XSS attack hole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java), hence the need for `<c:out>` to escape it.

And, you'd better use a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) instead of a [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) to deal with HTTP requests. See also [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax).