# How to fix XSS vulnerability in java jsp pages?

Tags: jsp, xss

I have below code to avoid xss-prevention

Issues but seems it's not working

```
<TD width="100%" class="InputColumn" colspan="2">
<TEXTAREA NAME="txt_name" ROWS="9" COLS="178"fld="ccom" onblur="javascript:trimInnerSpaces(this)"onchange="javascript:setccomSaveFlag();"><%=ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(StUpCom)%></TEXTAREA>
</TD>
```

Comment: How is it not working?  Is it crashing, or is it just not doing what you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2658941/1140748

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSS prevention in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java)

Comment: its working fine but not able to prevent xss issues

Comment: Unrelated: for escaping HTML see JSTL `c:out` http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html

Comment: Looks like you have javascript code working with your textarea. In such case encodeForHTML() is not enough to prevent XSS. You may need additionally to use encodeForJS(). See this guide: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Anyway it would be easier to answer if you provide the xss attack example that breaks your code.