# How to unescape HTML tags with JSTL

Tags: jsp, escaping, jstl

I have to show some content with already escaped HTML tags in page with JSTL.

I know that the`excapeXml` is for escaping characters that can be interpreted as markup. But seems it's only working for plain and unescaped HTML: `<p>This is the news</p>`, it doesn't work correctly for already escaped HTML: `&lt;p&gt;This is the news&lt;/p&gt;`.

So, how can I unescape already escaped HTML with JSTL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSTL doesn't offer tags or functions specifically for unescaping HTML (nor XML). Your closest bet is the `fn:replace()` as shown below assuming that the unescaped HTML content in question is provided via `${bean.content}`.

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
${fn:replace(fn:replace(bean.content, '&lt;','<'), '&gt;','>')}
```

It only becomes ugly and tedious in case you have more characters which need to be unescaped than only `<` and `>`.

Your safest bet is to bring in a custom EL function which in turn invokes [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) [`StringEscapeUtils#unescapeXml()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeXml(java.lang.String)) or perhaps [`unescapeHtml4()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4(java.lang.String)) method. If not done yet, [download](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) and drop `commons-lang.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Then create a `/WEB-INF/functions.tld` file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <display-name>Custom Functions</display-name>    
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>f</short-name>
    <uri>http://example.com/functions</uri>

    <function>
        <name>unescapeXml</name>
        <function-class>org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String unescapeXml(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Finally just use it as below:

```
<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://example.com/functions" %>
...
${f:escapeXml(bean.content)}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, I would personally take a step back. Why exactly do you have escaped HTML at hands in first place? This is strange. Normally, escaping is supposed to happen during HTML-rendering only. I'd rather lookup the one responsible for escaping that HTML and then change it as such that it doesn't unnecessarily escape HTML anymore. Perhaps the one responsible for that didn't really understand the concepts around HTML-escaping in web pages and manually performed escaping during request processing as part of an unthoughtful XSS prevention attempt. This is then food for read: [XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application).

Comment: Thanks for editing and answering my question. If JSTL can not work for unescaping HTML, which I'm not sure, then this is a great solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you consider using JSP custom tag? By using custom tag you can have more control for your tag.

http://javatips.info/jsp-custom-tag.html

For your case, you can find example 2 or 4 in the post.

Put your content as body of the tag in your jsp:

```html
<%@taglib uri="http://javatips.info/simple-tag" prefix="spl"%>
 
<spl:splWithBody color="red" headerColor="cyan">&lt;p&gt;This is the news&lt;/p&gt;</spl:splWithBody>
```

**Output in web browser:**

SimpleTagSupport: with body -> <p>This is the news</p>

Comment: Thank you. I'm using JSTL, so just wanna find out how it can be fixed. Thanks for your information, if the content is not fixed or my question is not answered as I expected, this will be the best solution.

Comment: What kind of JSTL are you using? Let see I can help you or not :)

Comment: Do you mean the version? 1.2. Or the tag I use: <c:out value="" escapeXml="" />?

Answer (score -1):

Just use the code below:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
...
<c:out value="${yourEscapedHTML}" escapeXml="false" />
...
```

Comment: Nope. Please re-read the question.

Comment: The question is: "How can I unescaped already escaped HTML with JSTL?" My answer works for the case printout of the unescaped HTML from the escaped HTML.

Comment: Nope. If it works for you, then your HTML wasn't **already** escaped. In your specific case you don't need the `<c:out>` at all. Just print `${yourEscapedHTML}` directly for the same result (and rename the variable because it actually isn't escaped).

Comment: This is my input: Department1&lt;br&gt;Department2&lt;br&gt;Department3.