# Java Wrapper Class: getParameterValues(String name) not working

Tags: java, arrays, servlets, wrapper

I have created a wrapper class to validate all the input parameters by assigning them into an array. I am getting request from Filter class. getParameterValues is not working which I am using to get the request parameters into an array.

```
        public class XSSRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {  

            public XSSRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
              super(servletRequest);       
            }
```

Following code works fine

```
             public String getParameter(String name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    return super.getParameter(name);
             }
```

Following doesn't work at all

```
            public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                  return super.getParameterValues(name);
            }
```

Following is the filter.java

```
 //@WebFilter("/filter")
public class filter implements Filter {


    public filter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    chain.doFilter(new XSSRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request), response);


    }
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

}

Comment: instead of `String[]` shouldn't it be `char[]'? My Java is very rusty but I remember having a similar issue in my first year of uni.

Please include error codes!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no error or exception. It is just not getting called at all.

Comment: If it's not getting called at all, then shouldn't you be including the code where you call these functions? So that we can see where the error currently lies?

Comment: String[] getParameterValues(String parameter)  is HttpServletRequestWrapper class method and so is getParameter(String parameter). One of them is working and the other is not. Both are inside the Wrapper class.

Comment: Food for thought: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2658922