# Cross site scripting issue in jsp

Tags: jsp, xss

How to resolve xss issue on

I have tried like below in sample.jsp

form:options items="${some} htmlescape=true

still xss issue exists.

If tried like below in sample.jsp

form:options items="${fn.escapeXml(some)}

now xss issue no more exsits but then application is not working for this page sample.jsp...showing like invalid type of string for option items. 
Any help is appreciated.. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are using ${obj.name} where obj is the class name of getter and setter methods and name is the string parameter.iam not sure abt the freemarker.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application

Comment: The suggestion also throw error invalid type of string for option items...as it is not value parameter in form...iam using items parameter in form:options tag..

Comment: Issue resolved...thanks user

Comment: @Priyanka can you please post an answer to this question.