# How to get data into textarea using expression language in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, textarea, el

I have some data that is store through textarea and I need to retrieve that data back into the textarea whenever i click edit button:

```
<textarea row="5" col="40" name="description"></textarea>
```

I want this textarea value back into the same textarea when edit button is clicked. I have used EL like this one:

```
 <textarea row="5" col="40" name="description" value="${param.description}"></textarea>
```

But this shows that `Undefined attribute name (value)`

How can I get value into textarea using EL(Expression Language)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the value inside textarea tag:

```
<textarea row="5" col="40" name="description">${param.description}</textarea>
```

Follow @BalusC comment , see [How to prevent XSS attack in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application)

Comment: Warning: this answer exposes a XSS attack hole.