# How to Fix XSS on hidden fields

Tags: jsp, xss, java-security

There is XSS vulnerability in one of the JSP file, where we have used hidden fields. Thus following hidden fields are vulnerable to xss:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="input1" value="<%=dummyInputValue%>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="input2" value="<%=dummyInputValue1%>"/>
```

where ***dummyInputValue*** comes from request object..something like below ***request.getParameter("dummyInputValue")***

I am not sure how to fix this fields to avoid xss vulnerability. Kindly help me on this.

By accessing the following URL (example):

http://localhost:7001/app1/PeopleSearch.jsp?input1=%22%3e%3csCrIpT%3ealert(83676)%3c%2fsCrIpT%3e&input2=dummyValue1

Triggering the XSS requires alt+shift+x (windows) or ctrl+alt+x (max).

Comment: Show your JSP code. Anyway, you can start here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658941/3511123

Comment: sorry Jozef, I have updated JSP code for the hidden fields now

Comment: Thank you Jozef, your reference link fixed my issue adding the JSTL code                                   <input type="hidden" name="input1" value="<c:out value="${dummyInputValue}"/>"/>         ..Sorry, I am not sure how to format the code while adding comment

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, after reading the comment given by Jozef. XSS is prevented in JSP by using JSTL  tag. That is by changing the code as below

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<input type="hidden" name="input1" value="<c:out value="${dummyInputValue}"/>"/>
```