# Efficient way to apply xss crosssite scripting for encoding jsp/servlet application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, xss, validationframework

I am working on a jsp/servlet application, now the requirement is to apply cross-site scripting , as it is a huge application that contains around 200 jsp pages,and it is time taken to encode each jsp page  so I am looking for a efficient way to do this so that it reduces the efforts, like can we do this in a Servlet filter, or an good framework to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application)

Comment: Hi Jonathan, this link is actually explaining how to implement xss  but I am looking for a solution which is kind of a generic I dont want to implement it in each jsp.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. we had lots of page of jsp ( more than 10000 pages, very huge project) so as you know XSS attack vulnerability would potentially occurred when you do something like this:

```
<div><%=someValue%></div>
```

So there are two options for us here:

**1)** use `<c:out>` tag from jsp which insure us that XSS attack won't happen. Something like this:

```
<div><c:out value="<%=someValue%>" /></div>
```

which is not so hard to apply this for all your 200 pages.

**2)** write some java codes to check if the value has XSS volnerability.
You might get `someValue` from a Java class like this:

```
String someValue = MyClass.getSomeValue();
```

So in `getSomeValue` method you should check some patterns.

I wrote some Java patterns for XSS detection and I bring them for you here:

```
private static Pattern[] patterns = new Pattern[]{
        // Script fragments
        Pattern.compile("<script>(.*?)</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
        // src='...'
        Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\'(.*?)\\\'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
        Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\"(.*?)\\\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
        // lonely script tags
        Pattern.compile("</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
        Pattern.compile("<script(.*?)>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
        // eval(...)
        Pattern.compile("eval\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
        // expression(...)
        Pattern.compile("expression\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
        // javascript:...
        Pattern.compile("javascript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
        // vbscript:...
        Pattern.compile("vbscript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
        // onload(...)=...
        Pattern.compile("onload(.*?)=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL)
};

public static Boolean strongCheckForXSS(String input) {
    if (input == null)
        return false;
    for (Pattern p : patterns)
        if (p.matcher(input).find())
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so is there any framework available in market to achieve this.