# Xss prevention in JSP

Tags: jsp, jsoup, jstl, xss, owasp

XSS is well known vulnerability in JSP. There are lot of information on web (and on stack overflow) about preventing XSS in JSP.

I have found printing user input with `<c:out>` is most commonly used approach. It escapes xml characters.

Second approach is using *Jsoup* or *Owasp* libraries for sanitizing user input. They escape html characters.

I have tried using Jsoup for sanitizing user input. It works well for html based XSS attacks, but it does not sanitize characters like: *"*. XSS attacks are possible as *"* can close html attribute tag and add malicious script inside tag.

I have tried using `<c:out>` to print user input in JSP. It seems to protect against all XSS attacks, but I can't find is that assumption correct on web.

There are similar questions of stack overflow, but none of them answers following question: "**Is `<c:out>` used for printing user input on JSP protecting against all XSS attacks?**". (If it is not how can I prevent XSS attacks in JSP)

Comment: Question is not same as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application). Answer is not explicit about if <c:out> alone is 100% XSS safe

Comment: Yes. First paragraph of currently top ranked answer says literally: *"XSS can be prevented in JSP by using JSTL `<c:out>` tag or `fn:escapeXml()` EL function when (re)displaying **user-controlled input**."*.

Comment: I think you got confused wrt "escaping" versus "sanitizing". I improved the answer in the duplicate question to add a clarification.

Comment: I am confused with `Jsoup.clean(stringVar, Whitelist.none())` . It sanitizes `stringVar` + it escapes characters: `<` and `>` .