# XSS attacks in jsp

Tags: java, security, jsp

Hi 
I have a jsp page in which  following lines

```
if(Exception err) {
  out.println (err.getMessage() + "<br/><br/>");
}
```

may get XSS attacks i want to it just display the above things without any XSS attacks
Any thought ?

Comment: unless I'm missing something (e.g. there is code you meant to post that got lost) there are no variables, parameters or SQL used in the above code that could be hijacked.

Comment: The code you've shown is not prone to XSS as there's nothing dynamic in it.  Please post something more resembling your real code if you want help.

Comment: @scunlife, if err.getMessage() contains data from the user (ex. wrong input) than there is a possibility of XSS.

Answer (score 3):

use [`c:out`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) tag.

**Also See**

- [java-best-practices-to-prevent-cross-site-scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159729/java-best-practices-to-prevent-cross-site-scripting)

Comment: it's not possible to write scriptlet in c:out tag

Comment: It is also not recommended to write scriptlet in jsp. what you want to write exactly ??

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons provides StringEscapeUtils, see the [escapeHtml()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) method