# Escape HTML entities in JSP / JSPX: no solution for problem that should not even exist?

Tags: jsp, escaping, jspx

We use jspx as template engine. We have dozen of screens with hundreds of el expressions like ${user.firstName} or "${mail.subject}"

And all this HTML code is not escaped by default. If there would be something with < or " in field -- screen will fail. We can always use fn:escapeXml but doing so in all places really boring.

1)
Does there is a way to do escape by default?

The only way I know is to hack JSP compiler (like jasper for tomcat). But it is not a way to go.

2)
Why somebody may ever need unescaped HTML in el? Storing HTML outside of template (in database for example) is not a good practice.

3) I am sure template engine should handle it automatically (as it done in XSLT), why should user care about it?
Manual escaping (fn:escapeXml) smells like SQL manual escaping (which is used instead of JDBC setParam): boilerplate code and good place for sql-injection (cross-site scripting in our case).

Answer (score 11):

> *1) Is there a way to do escape by default?*

Not in the vintage JSP. Its successor Facelets, however, escapes them by default. The only way to disable escaping is to use `<h:outputText value="#{bean.foo}" escape="false" />` instead of `#{bean.foo}`.

---

> *2) Why somebody may ever need unescaped HTML in el? Storing HTML outside of template (in database for example) is not a good practice.*

Storing [sanitized](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) HTML is however more than commonly done. E.g. to allow a small subset of innocent HTML tags like `<p>`, `<b>`, `<i>` and on from which the `on*` attributes are already stripped.

---

> *3) I am sure template engine should handle it automatically (as it done in XSLT), why should user care about it? Manual escaping (fn:escapeXml) smells like SQL manual escaping (which is used instead of JDBC setParam): boilerplate code and good place for sql-injection (cross-site scripting in our case).*

JSP is an ancient view technology. It's not really a flexible template engine.

SQL injections are usually to be prevented by just using `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` (or by using an ORM framework instead of "raw JDBC", like as your XSS issue can be prevented by just using a MVC framework instead of "raw JSP").

---

As to your concrete problem, well, you can solve this in basically 4 ways:

1. Bite the bullet and replace all EL-in-template-text which redisplays user-controlled input by `fn:escapeXml()` or `<c:out>` and teach yourself and your team to pay attention to this in the future. Hint, a bit decent IDE like Eclipse has a regex based find-and-replace-in-all-files.
2. Have sort of DB interceptor which strips malicious HTML before inserting in DB. If necessary run a DB script to sanitize the existing data. This is however more a workaround than a real solution.
3. Replace the JSP EL resolver by a custom one which escapes all the HTML. This has however the disadvantage that you can never show plain HTML by EL whenever really needed.
4. Use a decent MVC framework with builtin HTML escaping. This is however more work than just fixing the individual EL expressions.

Comment: Thanks! We use struts + jspx, we do not want to use faces -- it is different technology. 1) We use intellij idea and can replace all elements but we do not like this way. 2) escaping is VIEW issue and must be solved on the view layer, not in database. 3) To do so I need to hack my container. I can register my custom ELResolver but it will be used in chain, I can not disable or wrap all other resolvers (I do not even have even pointers to them -- JSP EL API is very bad). 4) We use struts. It uses ServletDispatcher to resolve jsp views. We can play with it's EL but I am not sure it works

Comment: Then bite the bullet. That's what you get paid for. Learn the lesson for the next time.

Comment: I think there is a 5th option you could add which is not to use JSP but a different view technology like Scalate, Velocity, or Freemaker. For those template languages its easier to do cross cutting stuff.

Comment: @Adam: or the lovely Facelets.

Comment: I know you love Facelets :) (or maybe you like writing about it often). Of course another option is to use my little pet project: http://code.google.com/p/jatl/ . ie just use Java. I mean he is already using struts.. it can't be any worse :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible to escape all EL-expressions by default. This can be done by registrating a custom [ELResolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html). See for instance this site for an example of how it can be done:  http://pukkaone.github.com/2011/01/03/jsp-cross-site-scripting-elresolver.html