# Should I use <h:outputText> to print static text?

Tags: jsf-2

Should I use `<h:outputText value="static text"/>` or directly write `static text` into the `xhtml` file to print text that is static?

Example - with output text:

```
<h:outputText value="User Name:"/>
<h:outputText value="#{currentUser.name}"/>
```

Example - directly:

```
User Name:
<h:outputText value="#{currentUser.name}"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just  write it directly into the page without the outputText. You even can write el expressions without a tag. So you could write:

```
User name: #{currentUser.name}
```

The outputText is needed (among others) if you want to change the text with ajax, render it conditionally or if you want to apply certain styles to the text.

Comment: Or when you want to disable implicit HTML escaping.

Comment: An `#{currentUser.name}` without `h:outputText` does not escape the content, right?

Comment: @Ralph: no, it **is** escaped. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf/7725675#7725675