# The listener for p:selectOneMenu working only partially

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a simple JSF form which has three dropdowns, 
here is the code:

```
<h:form>
            <p:panel header="Select country" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <p:outputLabel for="country" value="Country: " />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{phaseOneController.country}" style="width:150px">
                        <p:ajax listener="#{phaseOneController.onCountryChange}" update="province" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Country" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{phaseOneController.countries}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel for="province" value="Province: " />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="province" value="#{phaseOneController.province}" style="width:150px">
                        <p:ajax listener="#{phaseOneController.onProvinceChange}" update="city" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Province" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{phaseOneController.provinces}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:outputLabel for="city" value="City: " />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{phaseOneController.city}" style="width:150px">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select City" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{phaseOneController.cities}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>

                <p:separator />

                <p:commandButton value="Select" actionListener="#{phaseOneController.submit}" icon="ui-icon-check">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
```

Now when I select a country, the onCountryChange gets called but when I update the province, the onProvinceChange doesn't get called at all!! It is surprising how one would work and other wouldn't

Here is the piece of code from the controller:

```
public void onCountryChange() {
        System.out.println("On country change called");
    }

    public void onProvinceChange() {
        System.out.println("On province change called");
    }
```

For shortening the question I have replaced the code in the listener methods.

Answer: `For anyone who faces this issue, using HashMap to populate the dropdown solved the issue. I am not sure why list is giving so much trouble.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value)

Comment: What is the scope of     phaseOneController    bean?

Comment: Its RequestScoped

Comment: the update in `<p:ajax listener="#{phaseOneController.onCountryChange}" update="subCategory" />` will never work

Comment: @Kukeltje Well its update="province"

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  event="change"...

```
      <p:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{phaseOneController.country}" style="width:150px">
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{phaseOneController.onCountryChange}" update="subCategory" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Country" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{phaseOneController.countries}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:selectOneMenu id="province" value="#{phaseOneController.province}" style="width:150px">
                    <p:ajax  event="change" listener="#{phaseOneController.onProvinceChange}" update="city" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Province" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{phaseOneController.provinces}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing the bean in the view scope by `@ViewScoped` and Custom Converters to each `f:selectItems` should solve this problem.

#### Please See:

[Cascading p:selectOneMenu model value not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855074/cascading-pselectonemenu-model-value-not-set?answertab=votes#tab-top)