# JSF 2 - show plain html inside jsf-template

Tags: html, jsf-2, facelets

I have my sites content saved as plain html in my database. It is only simple data no input from the user is possible.
I like to show the content as follows:
if content.jsf?Sitename gets called i want to show the content of the site "Sitename".
I already have the content saved in my ApplicationScoped Bean.
content.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition template="template/common/commonLayout.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<ui:define name="content">
//show content here
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

I want to do this because, i'd like to add new pages/subpages without redeploying the whole application.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`<h:outputText escape="false">`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputText.html) to show plain HTML from a bean property.

```
<h:outputText value="#{yourApplicationScopedBean.html}" escape="false" />
```

If you want to parameterize it, use EL 2.2 feature of passing method arguments, or use a `Map`.

Beware of potential [XSS attack holes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf/7725675#7725675) if this concerns user-controlled data though.

Comment: thank you very much. I'm new to jsf. Can you please give me an example for the paramaterization by using a map?

Comment: Have a `Map<String, String>` property. Imagine that the desired HTML is been put in the map with the key `someKey`, then you can get it by `#{bean.map.someKey}`.

Comment: the first part I already had implemented like that. But what I don't get is the second part. First of all someKey is a key of the map? How do I get this key from the url (content.jsf?Sitename)?

Comment: You can get request parameters in EL by `#{param}` map. So e.g. `content.jsf?foo=bar` will give you string "bar" on `#{param.foo}`. So using `#{bean.map[param.foo]}` will return the map entry associated with string key "bar". To learn more about EL, see also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the part I was looking for!