# how to secure jsf 2 with primefaces application without spring-security.

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am working on jsf2 with primefaces 3.5 Application. I want to make my application secure from xss attacks, sql injection and post browsing. Suggest me how can I achieve this?. I don't want to introduce spring 3 security in my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSRF, XSS and SQL Injection attack prevention in JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf)

Comment: Spring Security has completely nothing to do with XSS and SQL injection, by the way. It's just an authorization/authentication framework (login user, check roles/permissions, etc). I'm not sure what you're talking about with "post browsing". Do you mean cached postbacks which are navigable and re-executable by browser's back button?