# Will <h:inputHidden> tag do the html encoding for the attribute value it renders?

Tags: jsf

Will `<h:inputHidden>` tag do the html encoding for the attribute value it renders?

I cannot find any documentation on this.

Comment: You could always try it you know.

Comment: I am not quite familiar with UI technology. In the code, there is something like following: ${param['xxx']} is the ${} a JSF recognized expression? Or it is a JBOSS SEAM expression since we used SEAM.

Comment: That's a completely new question.

Answer (score 0):

In JSF, **everything** is HTML-encoded, unless you explicitly set `escape="false"` attribute on the tag/component supporting that attribute (such as `<h:outputText>`).

This thus also covers the value of any `<h:inputXxx>` component.

#### See also:

- [CSRF, XSS and SQL Injection attack prevention in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf)