# Localization with Hindi language in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, localization, hindi

I'm using [this](http://vikku.info/indian-language-unicode-converter/hindi-unicode-converter.html) English to Hindi Unicode converter. The code produced is placed in the `MessageBundle_hi_IN.properties` file.

When a constraint is violated like a mandatory text field. A corresponding error message should be picked up from this file and displayed in Hindi language but it displays the same Unicode as in the file without any conversion like,

```
&#2326;&#2366;&#2354;&#2367; &#2344;&#2361;&#2367; &#2352;&#2326; &#2358;&#2325;&#2340;&#2375;&#46;
```

It is expected to be shown in Hindi like.

खालि नहि रख शकते.

It means "*Cannot be left blank.*"

---

The XHTML page.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="#{localeBean.language}"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

        <f:view locale="#{localeBean.locale}">

        <h:head>
            <title>Title</title>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>                

            <h:form>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="languages" value="#{localeBean.language}" onchange="submit();" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 50px;">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="en" itemLabel="English" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="hi" itemLabel="Hindi" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </h:form>

        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

The corresponding managed bean.

```
package admin.mangedbean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public final class LocaleBean implements Serializable
{
    private Locale locale;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LocaleBean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
    }

    public Locale getLocale()
    {
        return locale;
    }

    public String getLanguage()
    {
        return locale.getLanguage();
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language)
    {
        if(language.equals("hi"))
        {
            locale = new Locale(language, "IN");
        }
        else
        {
            locale = new Locale(language);
        }

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
    }
}
```

---

The faces-config.xml file.

```
<application>
    <message-bundle>
        messages.MessageBundle
    </message-bundle>

    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>hi_IN</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>

    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>messages.ResourceBundle</base-name>
        <var>messages</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

---

This works in JSP something like,

```
<fmt:setLocale value="hi_IN"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="bundles.resourceBundle_hi_IN" var="resourceBundle"/> 

<fmt:message key="someKey" bundle="${resourceBundle}"/>
```

What is going wrong here? Am I using a wrong [converter](http://vikku.info/indian-language-unicode-converter/hindi-unicode-converter.html)? Is this language not supported by JSF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This,

```
&#2326;&#2366;&#2354;&#2367; &#2344;&#2361;&#2367; &#2352;&#2326; &#2358;&#2325;&#2340;&#2375;&#46;
```

is the HTML-escaped form of Hindi. As part of [JSF's builtin XSS-attack prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf), any output text is implicitly HTML-escaped. So, effectively, this HTML-escaped Hindi ends up double-escaped in generated HTML as follows (rightclick, *View Source* to see it yourself):

```
&amp;#2326;&amp;#2366;&amp;#2354;&amp;#2367; &amp;#2344;&amp;#2361;&amp;#2367; &amp;#2352;&amp;#2326; &amp;#2358;&amp;#2325;&amp;#2340;&amp;#2375;&amp;#46;
```

Which causes it to appear in its original HTML-escaped form once interpreted by the webbrowser.

After all, using HTML-escaped form `&#XXXX;` in a `.properties` file is not the right approach. You should use Unicode-escaped form `\uXXXX` instead. See also the [javadoc of `java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). A bit decent IDE like Eclipse already does it automatically when you edit a file with `.properties` extension in a Java-flavored project. You can just type out Hindi in there the usual way and Eclipse will automagically escape it. If you're however using a different editor, or if you can't figure how to configure the editor right, then you'd need to use the JDK-provided `native2ascii` tool. Again, see the aforelinked Javadoc for detail.

Ultimately, the proper Unicode-escaped form of your Hindi looks like this (I copypasted after Eclipse escaped it):

```
\u0916\u093E\u0932\u093F \u0928\u0939\u093F \u0930\u0916 \u0936\u0915\u0924\u0947.
```

Put this unmodified in your `.properties` file.

That it works in legacy JSP is simply because it has as being a rather legacy and inferior view technology no form of implicit XSS attack prevention and therefore doesn't HTML-escape any template text.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, for the case you didn't already knew it, you can also just write Hindi straight in the source code of a Facelets file. You only need to make sure that your editor is configured to use UTF-8 to save text files. The converter you found is absolutely useless for modern JSF development.