# Using session bean created by JSF from a JSP

Tags: jsp, jsf

So I'm creating and managing a bean using a JSF. The JSF then links to a JSP page that I need access to the managed bean. The JSF code:

```
<h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{registration.lastName}"/>
<h:commandButton value="Register" action="confirm.jsp"/>
```

The JSP:

```
<jsp:useBean id = "registration" scope = "session"
    class = "Project1.Registration">
</jsp:useBean>

<%=
        registration.getFirstName()
%>
```

So, the JSP firstName is null. Can you use 'usebean' to get access to the JSF bean? Is there more I need to do to call the JSP and pass the managed bean? Obviously this is for a class and I wouldn't see a reason to mix the two like this, but alas that is the requirement. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes:

1. You do not need `<jsp:useBean>` if bean is already been created by some controller beforehand (such as JSF or even a plain vanilla servlet). Just directly access it by its name. It's as being a session scoped bean just available as a session attribute the usual EL way by `${registration}`.
2. Neither `<jsp:useBean>` nor EL variables are as direct variables available in *scriptlet* `<% ... %>` scope. Instead, just use EL the usual way. Even more, *scriptlets* are strongly discouraged since more than a decade. You should stop using them and configure your `web.xml` to disable them.

So, all in all just this should do:

```
<c:out value="${registration.firstName}" />
```

The `<c:out>` is technically not mandatory, you can also just use `${registration.firstName}`, but in contrary to Facelets, legacy JSP doesn't have [implicit HTML escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf/7725675#7725675). So using `<c:out>` is functionally mandatory in order to prevent XSS attack holes which can occur during redisplaying unsanitized user-controlled input inline in HTML output.

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)